# Slick slider artificially center

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery Slick Slider http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ which works perfectly.

I also have a separate script running which checks the page url and if a link in the slick slider has the same url then a class of `current` is added to that particular link.

This script is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    $('#slick a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).addClass('current');
});
```

This again works perfectly.

I am looking to extend this though so that the link with the class of `current` is  centered in the Slick Slider. If anyone knows how to do this then I would be very grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'centerMode' and 'slickGoTo' settings of the slick slider. centerMode will keep your current slide in the center. With your condition get the count of the element which is current and then using slickGoTo(count) you can center that element.
For more details see the settings menu http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/.